# Django Styling Issue - Can't get icons to display

Tags: css, svg, styling

I'm using a custom set of icons from a template from themeforest.

I can't get them to display using Django and I'm not sure why. Specifically the Icon images are not loading - there are blanks where they should be.

The styling is setup with static files, the rest of the site loads, and i assume it's to do with the styling linking to a bunch of .svg, .eot, .ttf, .woff files.

Thanks in advance - I've got most of it on github here, https://github.com/Hewlbern/Videography-Website

- Edit with Code*

Static File Structure

```
static/
css/
font-icons
font-icons-rtl
font-icons-snapchat
fonts/
a bunch of svg, eot, ttf files where I assume the images / icons are kept.
```

The HTML

```
<div class="common-height clearfix">


                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="max-height">
                            <div class="row common-height grid-border clearfix">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-mobile"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Responsive Framework</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-presentation"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Beautifully Presented</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-puzzle"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Extensively Extendable</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-gears"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Powerfully Customizable</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-genius"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Geniusly Transformable</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-padding">
                                    <div class="feature-box fbox-center fbox-dark fbox-plain fbox-small nobottomborder">
                                        <div class="fbox-icon">
                                            <a href="#"><i class="icon-et-hotairballoon"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <h3>Industrial Support</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Styling

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/et-line.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fonts.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/onepage.css' %}" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/dark.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-icons.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/responsive.css' %}" type="text/css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/plugins.js' %}"></script>
<!-- Footer Scripts
============================================= -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDMxJ92oBkSnVNHFX3R8XhtYQPEgk1_IiI"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/jquery.gmap.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'javascript/functions.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('.videoplay-on-hover').hover( function(){
            if( $(this).find('video').length > 0 ) {
                $(this).find('video').get(0).play();
            }
        }, function(){
            if( $(this).find('video').length > 0 ) {
                $(this).find('video').get(0).pause();
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(window).load(function(){

        // Google Map
        jQuery('#headquarters-map').gMap({
            address: 'Melbourne, Australia',
            maptype: 'ROADMAP',
            zoom: 14,
            markers: [
                {
                    address: "Melbourne, Australia",
                    html: "Melbourne, Australia",
                    icon: {
                        image: "images/icons/map-icon-red.png",
                        iconsize: [32, 32],
                        iconanchor: [14,44]
                    }
                }
            ],
            doubleclickzoom: false,
            controls: {
                panControl: false,
                zoomControl: false,
                mapTypeControl: false,
                scaleControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                overviewMapControl: false
            },
            styles: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"0.00"},{"lightness":"74"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"3"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
        });

    });

</script>
```

The CSS in question

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'font-icons';
        src:url('fonts/font-icons.eot');
        src:url('fonts/font-icons.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('fonts/font-icons.woff') format('woff'),
            url('fonts/font-icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('fonts/font-icons.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'lined-icons';
        src:url('fonts/lined-icons.eot');
        src:url('fonts/lined-icons.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('fonts/lined-icons.woff') format('woff'),
            url('fonts/lined-icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('fonts/lined-icons.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons';
        src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot');
        src:url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.woff') format('woff'),
            url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('fonts/Simple-Line-Icons.svg#Simple-Line-Icons') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"],
    [class^="icon-line-"], [class*=" icon-line-"],
    [class^="icon-line2-"], [class*=" icon-line2-"],
    .side-header #primary-menu ul > li.sub-menu > a:after {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'font-icons';
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: inherit;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

    [class^="icon-line-"], [class*=" icon-line-"] { font-family: 'lined-icons'; }

    [class^="icon-line2-"], [class*=" icon-line2-"] { font-family: 'Simple-Line-Icons'; }

    .icon-lg {
      font-size: 1.3333333333333333em;
      line-height: 0.75em;
      vertical-align: -15%;
    }
    .icon-2x {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    .icon-3x {
      font-size: 3em;
    }
    .icon-4x {
      font-size: 4em;
    }
    .icon-5x {
      font-size: 5em;
    }
    .icon-fw {
      width: 1.2857142857142858em;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .iconlist {
        padding-left: 0;
        margin-left: 1.75em;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .iconlist li { position: relative; }

    .iconlist ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 5px 0 5px 25px;
    }

    .iconlist > li [class^="icon-"]:first-child, .iconlist > li [class*=" icon-"]:first-child {
        position: absolute;
        left: -1.75em;
        width: 1.75em;
        text-align: center;
        top: 1px;
        width: 14px;
    }

    .iconlist.iconlist-large { font-size: 16px; }

    .iconlist.iconlist-large li { margin: 4px 0; }

    .iconlist.iconlist-large > li [class^="icon-"], .iconlist.iconlist-large > li [class*=" icon-"] {
        width: 16px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .iconlist-color li i { color: #1ABC9C; }

    .icon-border {
      padding: .2em .25em .15em;
      border: solid 0.08em #eeeeee;
      border-radius: .1em;
    }
    .icon.pull-left {
      margin-right: .3em;
    }
    .icon.pull-right {
      margin-left: .3em;
    }
    .icon-spin {
      -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
      -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
      -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
      animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    }
    @-moz-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes spin {
      0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
      }
    }
    .icon-rotate-90 {
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
      transform: rotate(90deg);

}
.icon-rotate-180 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.icon-rotate-270 {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.icon-flip-horizontal {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0, mirror=1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.icon-flip-vertical {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2, mirror=1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
.icon-stacked {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.icon-stacked-1x,
.icon-stacked-2x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon-stacked-1x {
  line-height: inherit;
}
.icon-stacked-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.icon-inverse {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.icon-type:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
.icon-box:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-archive:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-envelope:before {
    content: "\e603";
}
.icon-email:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-files:before {
    content: "\e605";
}
.icon-printer2:before {
    content: "\e606";
}
.icon-folder-add:before {
    content: "\e607";
}
.icon-folder-settings:before {
    content: "\e608";
}
.icon-folder-check:before {
    content: "\e609";
}
.icon-wifi-low:before {
    content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-wifi-mid:before {
    content: "\e60b";
}
.icon-wifi-full:before {
    content: "\e60c";
}
.icon-connection-empty:before {
    content: "\e60d";
}
.icon-battery-full:before {
    content: "\e60e";
}
.icon-settings:before {
    content: "\e60f";
}
.icon-arrow-left:before {
    content: "\e610";
}
.icon-arrow-up:before {
    content: "\e611";
}
.icon-arrow-down:before {
    content: "\e612";
}
.icon-arrow-right:before {
    content: "\e613";
}
.icon-reload:before {
    content: "\e614";
}
.icon-download:before {
    content: "\e615";
}
.icon-tag:before {
    content: "\e616";
}
.icon-trashcan:before {
    content: "\e617";
}
.icon-search:before {
    content: "\e618";
}
.icon-zoom-in:before {
    content: "\e619";
}
.icon-zoom-out:before {
    content: "\e61a";
}
.icon-chat:before {
    content: "\e61b";
}
.icon-clock:before {
    content: "\e61c";
}
.icon-printer:before {
    content: "\e61d";
}
.icon-home:before {
    content: "\e61e";
}
.icon-flag:before {
    content: "\e61f";
}
.icon-meter:before {
    content: "\e620";
}
.icon-switch:before {
    content: "\e621";
}
.icon-forbidden:before {
    content: "\e622";
}
.icon-phone-landscape:before {
    content: "\e623";
}
.icon-tablet:before {
    content: "\e624";
}
.icon-tablet-landscape:before {
    content: "\e625";
}
.icon-laptop:before {
    content: "\e626";
}
.icon-camera:before {
    content: "\e627";
}
.icon-microwave-oven:before {
    content: "\e628";
}
.icon-credit-cards:before {
    content: "\e629";
}
.icon-map-marker:before {
    content: "\e62a";
}
.icon-map:before {
    content: "\e62b";
}
.icon-support:before {
    content: "\e62c";
}
.icon-newspaper2:before {
    content: "\e62d";
}
.icon-barbell:before {
    content: "\e62e";
}
.icon-stopwatch:before {
    content: "\e62f";
}
.icon-atom:before {
    content: "\e630";
}
.icon-image:before {
    content: "\e631";
}
.icon-cube:before {
    content: "\e632";
}
.icon-bars:before {
    content: "\e633";
}
.icon-chart:before {
    content: "\e634";
}
.icon-pencil:before {
    content: "\e635";
}
.icon-measure:before {
    content: "\e636";
}
.icon-eyedropper:before {
    content: "\e637";
}
.icon-file-settings:before {
    content: "\e638";
}
.icon-file-add:before {
    content: "\e639";
}
.icon-file:before {
    content: "\e63a";
}
.icon-align-left:before {
    content: "\e63b";
}
.icon-align-right:before {
    content: "\e63c";
}
.icon-align-center:before {
    content: "\e63d";
}
.icon-align-justify:before {
    content: "\e63e";
}
.icon-file-broken:before {
    content: "\e63f";
}
.icon-browser:before {
    content: "\e640";
}
.icon-windows:before {
    content: "\e641";
}
.icon-window:before {
    content: "\e642";
}
.icon-folder:before {
    content: "\e643";
}
.icon-connection-25:before {
    content: "\e644";
}
.icon-connection-50:before {
    content: "\e645";
}
.icon-connection-75:before {
    content: "\e646";
}
.icon-connection-full:before {
    content: "\e647";
}
.icon-list:before {
    content: "\e648";
}
.icon-grid:before {
    content: "\e649";
}
.icon-stack3:before {
    content: "\e64a";
}
.icon-battery-charging:before {
    content: "\e64b";
}
.icon-battery-empty:before {
    content: "\e64c";
}
.icon-battery-25:before {
    content: "\e64d";
}
.icon-battery-50:before {
    content: "\e64e";
}
.icon-battery-75:before {
    content: "\e64f";
}
.icon-refresh:before {
    content: "\e650";
}
.icon-volume:before {
    content: "\e651";
}
.icon-volume-increase:before {
    content: "\e652";
}
.icon-volume-decrease:before {
    content: "\e653";
}
.icon-mute:before {
    content: "\e654";
}
.icon-microphone:before {
    content: "\e655";
}
.icon-microphone-off:before {
    content: "\e656";
}
.icon-book:before {
    content: "\e657";
}
.icon-checkmark:before {
    content: "\e658";
}
.icon-checkbox-checked:before {
    content: "\e659";
}
.icon-checkbox:before {
    content: "\e65a";
}
.icon-paperclip:before {
    content: "\e65b";
}
.icon-chat-1:before {
    content: "\e65c";
}
.icon-chat-2:before {
    content: "\e65d";
}
.icon-chat-3:before {
    content: "\e65e";
}
.icon-comment:before {
    content: "\e65f";
}
.icon-calendar:before {
    content: "\e660";
}
.icon-bookmark:before {
    content: "\e661";
}
.icon-email2:before {
    content: "\e662";
}
.icon-heart:before {
    content: "\e663";
}
.icon-enter:before {
    content: "\e664";
}
.icon-cloud:before {
    content: "\e665";
}
.icon-book2:before {
    content: "\e666";
}
.icon-star:before {
    content: "\e667";
}
.icon-lock:before {
    content: "\e668";
}
.icon-unlocked:before {
    content: "\e669";
}
.icon-unlocked2:before {
    content: "\e66a";
}
.icon-users:before {
    content: "\e66b";
}
.icon-user:before {
    content: "\e66c";
}
.icon-users2:before {
    content: "\e66d";
}
.icon-user2:before {
    content: "\e66e";
}
.icon-bullhorn:before {
    content: "\e66f";
}
.icon-share:before {
    content: "\e670";
}
.icon-screen:before {
    content: "\e671";
}
.icon-phone:before {
    content: "\e672";
}
.icon-phone-portrait:before {
    content: "\e673";
}
.icon-calculator:before {
    content: "\e674";
}
.icon-bag:before {
    content: "\e675";
}
.icon-diamond:before {
    content: "\e676";
}
.icon-drink:before {
    content: "\e677";
}
.icon-shorts:before {
    content: "\e678";
}
.icon-vcard:before {
    content: "\e679";
}
.icon-sun:before {
    content: "\e67a";
}
.icon-bill:before {
    content: "\e67b";
}
.icon-coffee:before {
    content: "\e67c";
}
.icon-tv2:before {
    content: "\e67d";
}
.icon-newspaper:before {
    content: "\e67e";
}
.icon-stack:before {
    content: "\e67f";
}
.icon-syringe:before {
    content: "\e680";
}
.icon-health:before {
    content: "\e681";
}
.icon-bolt:before {
    content: "\e682";
}
.icon-pill:before {
    content: "\e683";
}
.icon-bones:before {
    content: "\e684";
}
.icon-lab:before {
    content: "\e685";
}
.icon-clipboard:before {
    content: "\e686";
}
.icon-mug:before {
    content: "\e687";
}
.icon-bucket:before {
    content: "\e688";
}
.icon-select:before {
    content: "\e689";
}
.icon-graph:before {
    content: "\e68a";
}
.icon-crop:before {
    content: "\e68b";
}
.icon-heart2:before {
    content: "\e68c";
}
.icon-cloud2:before {
    content: "\e68d";
}
.icon-star2:before {
    content: "\e68e";
}
.icon-pen:before {
    content: "\e68f";
}
.icon-diamond2:before {
    content: "\e690";
}
.icon-display:before {
    content: "\e691";
}
.icon-paperplane:before {
    content: "\e692";
}
.icon-params:before {
    content: "\e693";
}
.icon-banknote:before {
    content: "\e694";
}
.icon-vynil:before {
    content: "\e695";
}
.icon-truck:before {
    content: "\e696";
}
.icon-world:before {
    content: "\e697";
}
.icon-tv:before {
    content: "\e698";
}
.icon-sound:before {
    content: "\e699";
}
.icon-video:before {
    content: "\e69a";
}
.icon-trash:before {
    content: "\e69b";
}
.icon-user3:before {
    content: "\e69c";
}
.icon-key:before {
    content: "\e69d";
}
.icon-search2:before {
    content: "\e69e";
}
.icon-settings2:before {
    content: "\e69f";
}
.icon-camera2:before {
    content: "\e6a0";
}
.icon-tag2:before {
    content: "\e6a1";
}
.icon-lock2:before {
    content: "\e6a2";
}
.icon-bulb:before {
    content: "\e6a3";
}
.icon-location:before {
    content: "\e6a4";
}
.icon-eye:before {
    content: "\e6a5";
}
.icon-bubble:before {
    content: "\e6a6";
}
.icon-stack2:before {
    content: "\e6a7";
}
.icon-cup:before {
    content: "\e6a8";
}
.icon-phone2:before {
    content: "\e6a9";
}
.icon-news:before {
    content: "\e6aa";
}
.icon-mail:before {
    content: "\e6ab";
}
.icon-like:before {
    content: "\e6ac";
}
.icon-photo:before {
    content: "\e6ad";
}
.icon-note:before {
    content: "\e6ae";
}
.icon-clock2:before {
    content: "\e6af";
}
.icon-data:before {
    content: "\e6b0";
}
.icon-music:before {
    content: "\e6b1";
}
.icon-megaphone:before {
    content: "\e6b2";
}
.icon-study:before {
    content: "\e6b3";
}
.icon-lab2:before {
    content: "\e6b4";
}
.icon-food:before {
    content: "\e6b5";
}
.icon-t-shirt:before {
    content: "\e6b6";
}
```

and more

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: please explain your problem with code

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the problem is. What are you having trouble loading?

Comment: Here we go guys - Hope that helps you out. Just ask for more information if it's needed.

Comment: Essentially the icon images are not loading.

Comment: I assume you mean you're having trouble loading the icon classes, for example `class="icon-et-gears"`. Are you sure you're loading the css and/or javascript where these are defined?

Comment: Yes I am. I think the issue comes from <i class ><> . 

Let me link you my styling just to make sure. I'll put it in another edit.

Comment: If you need anything else just ask. I'll give the directory structure as well.

Comment: Yes, add the directory structure.

Comment: I also added as much of the CSS as I could.

Comment: also included a github link.

https://github.com/Hewlbern/Videography-Website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly the CSS started working. I am not sure why but very glad it is working now. Perhaps there was a typo somewhere?

Thanks for the help regardless.